# how to switch classes in between different resolutions

Tags: css

How could i change classes actions in different screen resolutions.
For example i have

```
<div class="on-big on-small"></div>
```

so `on-big` will work till `1024 pixels` for example and `on-small` below `1024 pixels`

I was thinking just to make all properties to `0` or `none`, like puddings/margins etc. or making them with an !important property with media queries ofc. But i think it's a bad way of doing this

Comment: look for media queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you started with the concept of (mobile first) media queries. You hide the .on-big container "by default" and then only show it on resolutions over 1024 pixels:

.on-big {display: none}

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
 .on-big {display: block}
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries explains this in greater detail

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries..here's a sample code

```
<div class="md"></div>
@media (max-width:1024px) {
 .md{
 //do your thing for small devices
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
 .md{
  //do your thing for big devices
  }
}
```